# AutoFilling down to that last

Tags: excel, vba

I have this simple code to apply a 'Table' to a range.

However, it isn't autofilling down to the last value as it should. Can't see what I've done wrong with my 'end down' and 'end right'.

```vb
ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range([F22].End(xlDown), [F22].End(xlToRight)), , xlYes).Name = "Table1"
```

Comment: `End` will stop scanning at the next blank value it finds. So if there are any blanks in your data at all, `End` will not go to the end of the table. This is why many people prefer to do `Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` which is going from the bottom of the page, upwards until it finds any data. Its much more reliable.

Answer (score 1):

## Referencing a Range

### 3.) Your 'Executing' Line of Code

```
ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rg, , xlYes).Name = "Table1"
```

Note that the default name of the first table in a workbook is `Table1` making it possibly redundant in the line.

### 1.) The Worksheet

```vb
Dim ws As Worksheet
' This maybe safer...
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
' ... than this:
'Set ws = ActiveSheet
```

### 2.) The Range

```vb
Dim rg As Range
```

**CurrentRegion**

```vb
' This will work if the range is in table format i.e. no empty rows or columns.
Set rg = ws.Range("F22").CurrentRegion   

' But it may fail if there is data adjacent to the left or to the top
' when you will want to use:
Dim FirstCell As Range: Set FirstCell = ws.Range("F22")
With FirstCell.CurrentRegion
    Set rg = FirstCell.Resize(.Row + .Rows.Count _
        - FirstCell.Row, .Column + .Columns.Count - FirstCell.Column)
End With
```

**End**

```vb
Set rg = ws.Range("F22", ws.Cells(ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row, _
    ws.Cells(22, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column))
```

**UsedRange**

```vb
With ws.UsedRange
    Set rg = ws.Range("F22", .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count))
End With
```

**Find**

```vb
With ws.Cells
    Set rg = ws.Range("F22", ws.cells( _
        .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row, _
        .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column))
End With
```